# media query not operator

Tags: css, media-queries

Gidday

I've been trying to figure out making a media query that serve screens up to 660px a high res image, but not screens that are exactly 321px.

The purpose is to serve desktops/laptops etc and my desktop app that has a 321px viewport a normal low res image, while anything under 660 (excluding the 321px viewport) gets a high res image.

It works using these two queries, but the 320px viewport is requesting both images.  I could be lazy and leave it as is, as it achieves what I want display wise, but it's eating unnecessary bandwidth:

```
@media all and (min-width:661px){  //serves high res image to iphones etc (good), but also my 321px desktop app viewport (bad)
```

followed by...

```
@media all and (min-width: 661px), all and (width:321px) {  //serves low res image to desktops (good) and my 321px desktop app viewport (good)
```

I've been playing with the not operator in the first query, but haven't cracked it eg

```
all and (min-width:661px) and not (width:321px)
```

...but no go.

So how do I alter the first query to say...

allow for all under 660px, but ignore any that are 321px exactly?

Thanks for having a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some media queries. The last one is what you are looking for. Anything between 320px, and 322px it will show your body background as black. Just like saying ONLY show at 321px. Hope this helps!

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 660px) { body {background:red;} }

@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 322px) {body{background:#000;}}
```

Comment: Thanks JC - I missed your answer before I replied last night.  Much appreciated mate - I'll try your one.

Comment: Hey JC - I compared the two sets of media queries.  I found that yours downloaded both sets of images to the 321 screen (only 1 shows of course, but the headers show both images were being requested), which means unnecessary bandwidth etc .  I'm guessing it does this because the 321 screen fits the criteria for both media queries, whereas the other set of queries excludes 321 from the first query.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind - I think I cracked it without using not - here it is...

```
@media all and (min-width: 322px) and (max-width: 660px), (max-width: 320px) {  //hi res image for all screens 660px and below, excluding those exactly 321px
```

...followed by...

```
@media all and (min-width: 661px), all and (width:321px) { //low res image for all screens above 660px, plus those exactly 321px
```

Seems to be working how I wanted.